# How to fix this Firebase data retrieval?

Tags: php, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need some help in displaying all the values in a Firebase database, in a table.
As is, it is just displaying the first value in the table alone

Results:

[image]

```
var tblCodes = document.getElementById('tbl_qrcode_list');
var databaseRef = firebase.database().ref('qrcode/');
var rowIndex = 1;

databaseRef.once('value', function(snapshot) {
snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
var childData = childSnapshot.val();

var row = tblCodes.insertRow(rowIndex);
var cellId = row.insertCell(0);
var cellName = row.insertCell(1);
cellId.appendChild(document.createTextNode(childKey));
cellName.appendChild(document.createTextNode(childData.qrcode_desc));
rowIndex = rowIndex + 1;
 });
});

function save_code(){
var qrcode_desc = document.getElementById('qrcode_desc').value;
var qrcode_grp = document.getElementById('qrcode_grp').value;
var qrcode_stg = document.getElementById('qrcode_stg').value;
var qrcode_img = document.getElementById('qrcode_img').value;

var qrid = firebase.database().ref().child('qrcode').push().key;

var data = {
  qrcode_id: qrid,
  qrcode_desc: qrcode_desc,
  qrcode_grp: qrcode_grp,
  qrcode_stg: qrcode_stg,
  qrcode_img: qrcode_img,
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a cell for each value here  :

you need to create cells for each data

```
var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);

cellName.appendChild(document.createTextNode(childData.qrcode_desc));
cellName.appendChild(document.createTextNode(childData.qrcode_grp));
cell3.appendChild(document.createTextNode(childData.qrcode_id));
cell4.appendChild(document.createTextNode(childData.qrcode_img));
cell5.appendChild(document.createTextNode(childData.qrcode_stg));
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but now it doesn't populate the table with anything.

Result:
https://imgur.com/KGmCwK4

Comment: I forgot to get rid of the var key word

Comment: It saves to firebase like this: https://imgur.com/81PmLfR

But is displayed like this in the table: https://imgur.com/fLsxJhU

Comment: Ok I did not get your issue, i thought only the first row appeared

Comment: Oh, sorry for not being clear earlier, but is there a way to split the data being retrieved in the respective table fields?

Comment: In pure javascript it is painfull to manipulate tables, you could look up already made scripts or frameworks made to manipulate tables